# MySQL Optimize query to Enhance Performance for Comparison Report

Tags: mysql, database, jsp

I have two tables "`users`" and "`temp_users`". Now, "users" table contains millions of data and "temp_users" contains thousands. Both the table contains same sort of information but sometime some record might be missing.

So, the requirement is to compare these two tables and show the differences between them. I wrote the comparison Query but may be due to huge volume of data (millions) it is taking more than 5 minutes to execute. Any Suggestion??

The comparison query which I wrote is below:

```
SELECT 
   id,
   dateTime,
   phone,
   address 
FROM 
   tempUsers t1 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
   SELECT id,dateTime 
   FROM users t2 
   WHERE t1.id = t2.id 
   OR t1.dateTime=t2.dateTime
)
```

The system is developed in JSP and MySQL and is deployed in Apache Tomcat

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two Observations:

1. Did you really intend to have an 'OR' in your where clause?  Shouldn't it be an 'AND'?  'OR's can cause queries to run much slower if the query optimizer is unable to utilize indexes due to the 'OR' logic.
2. You are using a sub-select rather than a JOIN, and that can also cause a significant problem called 'correlated subquery' where the sub-select has to execute for every row being returned by the outer select.

The two issues above (correlated subquery with an OR condition) is likely what is causing the problem.

Try the following query instead:

```
SELECT 
   t1.id,
   t1.dateTime,
   t1.phone,
   t1.address 
FROM 
   tempUsers t1 
LEFT OUTER JOIN
   users t2
ON
   t1.id = t2.id 
   AND t1.dateTime=t2.dateTime
WHERE
   t2.id IS NULL
```

The above query performs a 'LEFT OUTER JOIN' using ID and DATETIME to join the two tables, then filters the results to only those where there is no row in USERS.  This should return what you want.

If the 'OR' condition really is the logic you need, then change it in the 'ON' clause, but be prepared that it could adversely affect the speed of the query.

For additional speed: ensure that there is an index on either 'id', 'dateTime', or both.

Hope this helps!

john...

Comment: Thanks a lot!! But I need OR because it is to compare the difference of either ID or subscription date not including both. But it did work. It is showing fast now.